# How to create a link of resources under virtual folder in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I m trying to create a virtual folder inside a folder in eclipse. I want to link some files to this virtual folder but I m not able to link.

Below is the sample code:

```java
IFolder folder = modelFolder.getFolder("Script_include");
folder.create(IResource.VIRTUAL, false, null);
IPath newLocation = new Path("/Users/dinesh.lodhi");
folder.createLink(newLocation, IResource.NONE, null);
```

What I exactly want is to create some virtual folders inside one of the folder at the startup of my plugin and want to link some of resources into it.

Answer (score 0):

The given path must be either an absolute file system path, or a relative path whose first segment is the name of a workspace path variable.

I was mistakenly using **folder.getFullPath()** for getting location.

and one more thing there is no need to 
  folder.create(IResource.VIRTUAL, false, null);
as createLink() method itself Creates a new file/folder resource as a member of this handle's parent resource.

Thanks